# How to parse a json and save it in a database?

Tags: php, sql, json, hierarchical-data

first sorry for my bad english.
I have a POST request with a json inside and i would save it in my database which has adjacency List model . It composed with 2 columns: `name` and `parent_id`,
How can i parse this json using php, then save it in my database. 
Any suggestions ? Thanks.

My json:

```
{
  "name": "Category 1",

  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Category 1.1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Category 1.1.1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Category 1.1.1.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Category 1.1.1.2"
            },
            {
              "name": "Category 1.1.1.3"
            }
          ]

        },

        {
          "name": "Category 1.1.2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Category 1.1.2.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Category 1.1.2.2"
            },
            {
              "name": "Category 1.1.2.3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Category 1.2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Category 1.2.1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Category 1.2.2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Category 1.2.2.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Category 1.2.2.2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you put some code snip here

Answer (score 1):

First we will decode the json using json_decode, after we will insert that to database, i hope this will help you

```
       <?php

       $jsonFile="children.json";
       $jsondata = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
       $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

        $array_data = $data['children'];

     //your database connection here
     $servername = "hostname";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
 foreach ($array_data as $row) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, ParentID) VALUES ('" . $row["name"] . "', '" . $row["ParentId"] . "')";
   $conn->query($sql);
 }
  $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the JSON, try using PHP's json_decode function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

I can't give you specifics on how to store it in the database without knowing what type of database it is, but you probably should use PHP's PDO (PHP Data Object) API. (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) It lets you prepare and execute queries/insertions/commands just like you can the database's shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
     Database query:  CREATE TABLE `stdtable` (
```

`std_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `std_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_age` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_num` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_postal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_dept` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_semstr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_major` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

```
*/
/* //JSON Data
   {
"stdID": "0106",
"stdData":{
    "stdName":"Mirwaise",
    "stdAge":"23",
    "stdGender":"Male",
    "stdNo":"12345",
    "stdAddress":{
        "stdStreet":"786 Street",
        "stdCity":"Riyadh",
        "stdCountry":"Saudi Arabia",
        "stdPostal":"98765"
    }
},
"stdEdu":{
    "stdDept":"Computer Science",
    "stdSemester":"8",
    "stdMajor":"Web Programming"
}
```

}

```
 */
//connect and select the database
$connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'cdn123', 'jsondb');

// get the contents of the JSON file 
$jsonCont = file_get_contents('studJson.json');

//decode JSON data to PHP array
$content = json_decode($jsonCont, true);

 //Fetch the details of Student
 $std_id = $content['stdID'];
 $std_name = $content['stdData']['stdName'];
 $std_age = $content['stdData']['stdAge'];
 $std_gender = $content['stdData']['stdGender'];
 $std_no = $content['stdData']['stdNo'];
 $std_street = $content['stdData']['stdAddress']['stdStreet'];
 $std_city = $content['stdData']['stdAddress']['stdCity'];
 $std_country = $content['stdData']['stdAddress']['stdCountry'];
 $std_postal = $content['stdData']['stdAddress']['stdPostal'];
 $std_dept = $content['stdEdu']['stdDept'];
 $std_sem = $content['stdEdu']['stdSemester'];
 $std_major = $content['stdEdu']['stdMajor'];

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."<br/>";

$valueStrings = '';
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $valueStrings .= "('".$std_name."', '".$std_age."', '".$std_gender."', '".$std_no."', '".$std_street."', '".$std_city."', '".$std_country."', '".$std_postal."', '".$std_dept."', '".$std_sem."', '".$std_major."'),";
}

$valueStrings2 = rtrim($valueStrings, ',');

//Insert the fetched Data into Database
$query = "INSERT INTO stdtable (std_name, std_age, std_gender, std_num, std_street, std_city, std_country, std_postal, std_dept, std_semstr, std_major)
VALUES ".$valueStrings2;

$result = $connect->query($query) or die("Cannot write");   

if($result) {
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute";
}

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."<br/>";
```

?>